# Hotkeys to redirect to different page

Tags: javascript, hotkeys

I had a simple script that when you pressed <kbd>C</kbd> you'd be redirected to a different page, same for other letters.
However, every time you would press the button this would happen, even if you were typing text into an input text field.

Can anyone write a lightweight script to allow me to make multiple hotkeys without them working in input fields or can show me where I can find documented explanations for this?

---

Okay, so I have the hotkey working, just can't make it stop.

```
$("input.registerform").keypress(function(e){

   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here is what I have to make it stop, the class of my input form is `registerform bgcolor2` but it won't work with `input.registerform`, nor with `input.registerform bgcolor2`.

I tried adding an ID to it with registerform as ID; didn't work either :/

Is it being caused by my AJAX? or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    $(document).keypress(function(e){

       if(e.which == 13){
      //Enter key is press do what you want
   }
   else if(e.which == 67 || e.which == 99){
      //C key is press do what you want

      //window.location.href = "urlToRedirect";
       alert("C pressed");
   }
    else if(e.which == 32){
        alert("Space pressed");

    }
       //Similarly check for as many conditions you want for different keys(ascii code)

    });

    //To supress this behavior do not happen in input field stop the event propagation

    $("input").keypress(function(e){
       //code goes here
       e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything :(

Comment: Can you post your code? Please try now parameter e was missing in the input keypress handler.

Comment: the hotkey itself doesn't work for some reason now, do I need any extra libraries to make this work?

Comment: You dont need any plugin to make it run, just jQuyer is required. Can you post your code?

Comment: What is the hotkey you are looking for?

Comment: $(document).keypress(function(){

   if(e.which == 13){
   }
   else if(e.which == 32){
      window.location.href = "/html/credits.php";
   }

   //Similarly check for as many conditions you want for different keys(ascii code)

});

I removed the last part for of the code for now to make hotkeys work in general but nothing :(

Comment: @sjaak - Please try my edited answer now it works fine. Take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kJKN2/.

Comment: Which key are you looking for? Make sure the keycode for that key is 32.

Comment: Tell me the key I will tell you or modify my answer.

Comment: See it works there, maybe its a problem with Ajax that I'm using on my site in general? cause it does bring up the alert just doesn't switch me to different page

Comment: I have added the condition for `Space` key take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kJKN2/1/

Comment: ok I got it to work now, however it does still switch page on field inputs, what do I exactly put at the last part of the code?

Comment: Do you have id or class to that input fields? Replace inputSelector by this input's selector, it will work fine.

Comment: so
$("input").keypress(function(e){
   //code goes here
   e.stopPropagation();
will change the ("input") my field id and it'll work? and I can repeat this code under it for different field?

Comment: I cant figure out last piece of code :S if I change it in someway it wont use hotkeys anymore, my class for fields it "registerform background2"

Comment: Use `$("input.registerform")` as the selector.

Comment: did that, now hotkeys work again but it wont block it in the fields :(

Comment: Anyone else has a solution?

$("input.registerform").keypress(function(e){


   e.stopPropagation();
});

Doesn't make it stop from happening :(

Comment: It workds perfectly fine the the fiddle. I am sure there is something wrong the in input selector. Post your markup I will give you the correct selector or can you try to alert `$("input.registerform").length` and see what you get.

Comment: <input type="text" class="registerform bgcolor2" name="to" value="<?php echo isset($tmpname) ? $tmpname : ""; ?>"/> that's the complete selector for some reason its just not working, not even with textfields

Comment: What did you see in the alert $("input.registerform").length?

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what you mean I replaced the whole last part with $("input.registerform").length but nothing happens? Sorry if i'm driving you crazy just started to add javascript features not too long ago

Comment: Man you need to send me your complete markup and js. I have tested it works perfectly fine. Created fiddle also http://jsfiddle.net/kJKN2/1/

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, I have all your code in a file called hotkeys.js, I'm calling this to my page where I have my input fields with <script =..."</script> however it keeps redirecting me.
And what exactly do I fill in under  $("input").keypress(function(e){ this part where you have added the // code goes here

Comment: Ah I finally got it!! now i'm just wondering about one thing, how can I do the same but for a textfield? replace input with textfield?

Comment: Okay so my problem was I had to add the whole code to every page where I have inputs, I couldn't just user <script type="text/javascript" src="/html/js/hotkeys.js"></script> for some reason it just wouldn't work.
Is there a fix for this? cause I dont think adding this whole code to about 50 pages is what I should be doing